# I cannot create my each loop to work for jQuery chart with Rails instance

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

*Hello folks, I am trying to display the player name and the money that he earns, unfortunately if I type the player just once it display only one player I know that I need to create each loop but I cannot make it works, can you help me please. The first line { y: "<%= result.FTAG %>", label: "<%= result.HomeTeam %>" } does not work but the second line works but it displays every time the same name because it is not in a loop. How to fix it?*

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</form>

<% @results.each do |result| %>
<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
  title:{
    text: "Top Oil Reserves"
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
  },
  data: [{        
    type: "column",  
    showInLegend: true, 
    legendMarkerColor: "grey",
    legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
    dataPoints: [      
      { y: "<%= result.FTAG %>", label: "<%= result.HomeTeam %>" },
      { y: 266455,  label: "<%= @player %>" },
      { y: 169709,  label: "<%= @player %>" },
      { y: 158400,  label: "<%= @player %>" },
      { y: 142503,  label: "<%= @player %>" },
      { y: 101500, label: "Kuwait" },
      { y: 97800,  label: "UAE" },
      { y: 80000,  label: "Russia" }
    ]
  }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script> <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating and setting up a new chart on every loop iteration and then throwing it all away. If you look at the rendered HTML source you'll see as many `window.onload() { ....}` calls as there are entries in `@results`.

You really just want to loop over your `@results` once array and build a inner datapoints payload - which you pass just once to the chart building function.

Something like this:

```
<script>
var datapoints = [];
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  datapoints.push({y: "<%= result.FTAG %>", label: "<%= result.HomeTeam %>"});
<% end %>
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function () {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
  title:{
    text: "Top Oil Reserves"
  },
  axisY: {
    title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
  },
  data: [{        
    type: "column",  
    showInLegend: true, 
    legendMarkerColor: "grey",
    legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
    dataPoints: datapoints
  }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
```

Comment: Cody, thank you very much, you saved my ass! Thank you a lot really! I just do not understand JS and Jquery that much thanks thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting @player correctly.  Without seeing the controller I can't say for sure but I am guessing you want result.HomeTeam.players rather than @player.

Comment: I will give you now the code + the controller in a plunket 1 second

Comment: This code displays the last player and the money like to_i